# Woklight Device Single Sign On

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, single-sign-on, worklight-security

I'm developing two android native applications using worklight where I want to share user id to enable SSO. Im using the android emulator to test both apps. I have defined the following security test for each application:

```
<mobileSecurityTest name="Authm">
        <testAppAuthenticity/>
        <testUser realm="BasicAuth" sso="true"/>
        <testDeviceId provisioningType="none"></testDeviceId>
</mobileSecurityTest>
```

I have also defined the shareduserId= com.ibm value for each application in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Am I missing something? Because I've been testing the app and if the users authenticates in the first app, still needs to be authenticated in the second.

Answer (score 3):

I have already found a solution. I decided to create a customSecurityTest to use it when invoking an adapter :

```
<customSecurityTest name="Auth">
            <test realm="BasicAuth" isInternalUserID="true" step="1"/>
</customSecurityTest>
```

**Important: You need to define the step number. If you don't define it ,the SSO will not work.**